# Maximum distance with Mongoid's Model.near method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, geolocation, mongoid

I've been using the geo near queries for a while now, but I can't seem to figure out how to limit the results to within a certain radius. For example, how do I limit the search to within 20 miles in this query?

```
Place.near(:coordinates => location.reverse) 
# must reverse the resulting coordinates array because mongo stores them backwards [lng,lat]
```

Answer (score 10):

The length of an arcdegree of north-south latitude difference, is about **60 nautical miles, 111 kilometres or 69 statute miles** at any latitude; You can read more about [here in wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Longitude#Degree_length) or in mongo geospatial page [The Earth is Round but Maps are Flat](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing).

Divide distance by 69 or 111 when using mile or km respectively, so now you can query it like this

```
Place.where(:coordinates => {"$near" => location.reverse , '$maxDistance' => 20.fdiv(69)})
```

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB supports a **maxDistance** attribute ([MongoDB Querying](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-Querying))

```
db.places.find( { loc : { $near : [50,50] , $maxDistance : 5 } } )
```

And the [mongoid_geo](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/mongoid-geo) extension has a **within_box** and **within_center** method.

Answer (score 1):

controller  :

```
lng, lat, dis = params[:lng], params[:lat], params[:dis]
page, per_page = params[:page] || 1 , params[:per_page] || 30
sms = SideMongo.geo_near([lng.to_f,lat.to_f], max_distance: dis.to_i, unit: "km".to_sym, spherical: true).sort_by!{|r| r.geo[:distance] }
page_sms = sms.per(per_page).page(page)
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Mongoid 4.0... returns an ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

The $maxDistance required by Mongo is in radians, so you need to convert the distance at the surface of the earth into a latitude/longitude angle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/

angle (radians) = distance_at_surface / radius_of_earth

angle = 10km / 6371km

angle = 10sm / 3960sm